# How can I sort my sql query by changing variable?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have this

```
$order = $_POST['order'];
$query = mysql_query("select wins from $usertable where id='$id' ORDER BY '$order' DESC");
```

Now the $order echoes properly but the $query doesn't return anything after returning it properly. Can anyone help me understand why ?

Comment: Dont enclose your `mysql_query()` function in quotes. Also, escape your `$_POST` data.

Comment: how do i escape the data ?

Comment: **Warning:** You've create a classical security vulnerability which allows a hacker to do anything with your database he likes, including manipulating and deleting data. For details about what the mistake is and how to prevent it, inform yourself about [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes from `$id` and `$order` variable

> $query = mysql_query("select wins from $usertable where id=$id ORDER
>   BY $order DESC");

It will work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

If $id or $order are intended to be numeric, it doesn't need to be in single quotes, just sanitized.

Replace your mysql_query with mysqli_query, as the former is deprecated.
You also need to sanitize that post data to protect against injection.

Answer (score -1):

try this

$query = mysql_query("select wins from $usertable where id='$id' ORDER BY '$order' DESC");